# throw MissingPluginException('No implementation found for method $method on channel $name');

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

i have a flutter app and i use google sign in with Firebase, but i run app and click in sign in button there is an error while debug

```
 if (result == null) {
  if (missingOk) {
    return null;
  }
  throw MissingPluginException('No implementation found for method $method on channel  $name');
}
return codec.decodeEnvelope(result) as T?;
}
```

any help please?

Comment: Stop your app and run it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Solve is so easy just stop your app and run it again
i hope this is useful